# ionic 2 camera/gallery images edit by adding some text, logo etc

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am building an Ionic2 app which uses a camera to take a photo or can look up in a gallery to choose a photo.

I want to edit the taken photo right away by adding some text over it and putting a logo in one corner. I have a select list above the image where the user selects few options and those values will be added on the image.

My html:

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
     <button ion-button (click)="takePicture()">
       <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
     </button>
     Latest Picture:
     <img [src]="base64Image" *ngIf="base64Image" />
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

 <img [src]="imageSrc" *ngIf="imageSrc"/>
 <ion-fab right bottom>
  <button ion-fab color="dark" (click)="openGallery()" >
    <ion-icon name="images"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-fab>
```

And my .ts :

```
takePicture(){
    Camera.getPicture({
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        targetHeight: 1000,
        allowEdit: true,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    }).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is a base64 encoded string
        this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }

  private openGallery (): void {
  let cameraOptions = {
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,      
    quality: 100,
    targetWidth: 1000,
    targetHeight: 1000,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,      
    correctOrientation: true
  }

  Camera.getPicture(cameraOptions)
    .then(file_uri => this.imageSrc = file_uri, 
    err => console.log(err));   
}
```

Right now it looks like following:
[image]
[image]

First screenshot shows the select text, and second screenshot shows an image chosen from the gallery that is shown in the app. Exactly like that image I should be able to add text, symbol, logo on my captured image.

How can I do it?

Comment: just guessing here but probably the same way you would like you do with cards -> http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#card-background . I guess you just need to sort the positioning on the element. You should box elements with the top level class = position:relative and child classes can then be position:absolute . Or flex box it

Comment: That's a nice though and input! Thanks,I will try it!